# Overriding Static Method in Java JAR

Tags: java, jar, classpath, static-methods

In a project that I'm working on, I have a library of code that I want to be shared across multiple Java projects.

In this library, I have a static function that I need to call. However, the functionality of this call needs to change depending on the project it is in. For instance, assume I have:

```
public class CommonCode
{
    public void foo ()
    {
        A.bar();
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
package x.y.z;

public class A
{
    public static void bar()
    {
        // This functionality varies based on the project
    }
}
```

Now, I have managed to get this to work by placing an identically named file at the same package in my own project, so it's before the JAR in the classpath. Such as:

```
package x.y.z;

public class A
{
    public static void bar()
    {
        // Custom code that requires other knowledge of my local project
    }
}
```

This works, but as I've read online, this is not generally considered a "good" solution and should be considered a last resort.

I was wondering what a better way of resolving this would be/how bad this really is if I have full control over the project when it is run.

Comment: Use a Factory Pattern which returns the instance of the class which should be used (note, this removes the requirement for static on the method). You could then use a configuration file which describes the which class you want to use, which you could dynamically load at runtime

Comment: So you're saying have an abstract Factory included in the library and then extend that into a concrete class in my individual projects? And load that class in the library code?

Comment: Why don't you just make some interface that contains `bar()`, and pass an object inheriting from said interface to your library?

Comment: I was thinking the factory would be concrete and return an abstract class or interface which implanted the functionality

Comment: This one of those examples where static is over rated ;)